# Time-out until restart

Tags: php, nosql, cassandra, phpcassa

I set up a cassandra cluster with 2 nodes. After a couple thousand of writes, it starts throwing TimeOut exceptions that don’t go away until after I restart the cassandra services. I am using phpcassa (latest at time of writing).

**Cassandra.yaml both**

- cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
- seed_provider:
- - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
- parameters:
- - seeds: "192.168.2.101"
- rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
- rpc_port: 8080

**Cassandra.yaml 1**

- initial_token: 0
- listen_address: 192.168.2.101

**Cassandra.yaml 2**

- initial_token: 85070591730234615865843651857942052864
- listen_address: 192.168.2.102

Assuming this configuration is correct, there must be an issue with my code. Here’s the test script I made to reproduce the error:

```
$pool = Config::ConnectionPool();
$stressTest = new ColumnFamily($pool, 'TwitterTest');
$id = 392766928478932992;

while(true)
{
    try
    {
        $stressTest->insert($id++, array("analyzed"=>0, "followersCount"=>"35",
            "friendsCount"=>"30", "lang"=>"en", "listedCount"=>"0",
            "name"=>"Henky Tanky", "statusesCount"=>"X", "text"=>"@HERPDERP dude i kno i lost a 16gb flash drive #MEH",
            "time"=>"2013-10-22 23:38:27", "twitterId"=>"392766928478932992", "username"=>"mehzor"),
            null, null, \cassandra\ConsistencyLevel::ANY);
    }
    catch (Exception $ex){
        print_r($ex);
        exit;
    }
}

class Config {
    static function ConnectionPool(){
        return new ConnectionPool('KSTwit', array('192.168.2.101:8080', '192.168.2.102:8080'));
    }
}
```

With that config I get a 'cassandra\TimedOutException' (Stacktrace 1)

```
// Set max-retries to 5, and read/write timeout to 60 seconds
new ConnectionPool('KSTwit', array('192.168.2.101:8080', '192.168.2.102:8080'), NULL, 5, 60000, 60000);
```

With that config I get a 'Thrift\Exception\TTransportException' (Stacktrace 2)

I have tried various ConsistencyLevels;
ONE, QUORUM and ANY. Same issue with all of them.

As I said, the exceptions don’t occur until after a couple throusand of writes. However, if I restart the script after an exception ocurred it will throw exceptions immediately. I have to restart the cassandra services and then it can take a couple thousand again. This only seems to occur with writes. It also occurs if I don’t use counter columns so it’s not an issue with that.

**Stack trace 1**

```
Error performing add on 192.168.2.101:8080: exception 'cassandra\TimedOutException' in /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/Thrift/Base/TBase.php:206
Stack trace:
#0 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/cassandra/Cassandra.php(3575): Thrift\Base\TBase->_read('Cassandra_add_r...', Array, Object(Thrift\Protocol\TBinaryProtocolAccelerated))
#1 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/cassandra/Cassandra.php(768): cassandra\Cassandra_add_result->read(Object(Thrift\Protocol\TBinaryProtocolAccelerated))
#2 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/cassandra/Cassandra.php(728): cassandra\CassandraClient->recv_add()
#3 [internal function]: cassandra\CassandraClient->add('All Tweets', Object(cassandra\ColumnParent), Object(cassandra\CounterColumn), 1)
#4 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/phpcassa/Connection/ConnectionPool.php(264): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/phpcassa/ColumnFamily.php(44): phpcassa\Connection\ConnectionPool->call('add', 'All Tweets', Object(cassandra\ColumnParent), Object(cassandra\CounterColumn), 1)
#6 /var/installstuff/cassphp/examples/db/TweetDatabase.php(103): phpcassa\ColumnFamily->add('All Tweets', 'Total')
#7 /var/installstuff/cassphp/examples/core/Helper.php(16): {closure}()
#8 /var/installstuff/cassphp/examples/db/TweetDatabase.php(104): Helper::DoForgiving(Object(Closure))
#9 /var/installstuff/cassphp/examples/core/twitterParser.php(98): TweetDatabaseCassandra->AddTweet('392633738364190...', Array)
#10 /var/installstuff/cassphp/examples/core/twitterParser.php(192): TwitterParser->RunOnce()
#11 /var/installstuff/cassphp/examples/runners/twitterParserCassandra.php(19): TwitterParser->Run()
#12 {main}
```

**Stack trace 2**

```
Error performing add on 192.168.2.101:8080: exception 'Thrift\Exception\TTransportException' with message 'TSocket: timed out reading 4 bytes from 192.168.2.101:8080' in /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/Thrift/Transport/TSocket.php:284
Stack trace:
#0 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/Thrift/Transport/TTransport.php(74): Thrift\Transport\TSocket->read(4)
#1 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/Thrift/Transport/TFramedTransport.php(139): Thrift\Transport\TTransport->readAll(4)
#2 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/Thrift/Transport/TFramedTransport.php(106): Thrift\Transport\TFramedTransport->readFrame()
#3 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/Thrift/Transport/TTransport.php(74): Thrift\Transport\TFramedTransport->read(4)
#4 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/Thrift/Protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php(305): Thrift\Transport\TTransport->readAll(4)
#5 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/Thrift/Protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php(197): Thrift\Protocol\TBinaryProtocol->readI32(NULL)
#6 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/cassandra/Cassandra.php(760): Thrift\Protocol\TBinaryProtocol->readMessageBegin(NULL, 0, 0)
#7 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/cassandra/Cassandra.php(728): cassandra\CassandraClient->recv_add()
#8 [internal function]: cassandra\CassandraClient->add('All Tweets', Object(cassandra\ColumnParent), Object(cassandra\CounterColumn), 1)
#9 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/phpcassa/Connection/ConnectionPool.php(264): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 /var/installstuff/cassphp/lib/phpcassa/ColumnFamily.php(44): phpcassa\Connection\ConnectionPool->call('add', 'All Tweets', Object(cassandra\ColumnParent), Object(cassandra\CounterColumn), 1)
#11 /var/installstuff/cassphp/examples/db/TweetDatabase.php(103): phpcassa\ColumnFamily->add('All Tweets', 'Total')
#12 /var/installstuff/cassphp/examples/core/Helper.php(17): {closure}()
#13 /var/installstuff/cassphp/examples/db/TweetDatabase.php(104): Helper::DoForgiving(Object(Closure))
#14 /var/installstuff/cassphp/examples/core/twitterParser.php(98): TweetDatabaseCassandra->AddTweet('392642135327264...', Array)
#15 /var/installstuff/cassphp/examples/core/twitterParser.php(192): TwitterParser->RunOnce()
#16 /var/installstuff/cassphp/examples/runners/twitterParserCassandra.php(19): TwitterParser->Run()
#17 {main}
```

The cassandra log doesn't really show anything interesting. Except for this ocurring a lot, but that happens even when the exceptions don't occur so I don't think it's the issue;

```
INFO 10:58:58,241 Timed out replaying hints to /192.168.2.102; aborting further deliveries
WARN 11:07:17,979 MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.  Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE; upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
```

Keyspace is setup using ‘SIMPLE_STRATEGY’ and ‘replication_factor=2’ According to the ‘nodetool ring’ command on both machines, the nodes are functioning ‘normal’ even after the exceptions have been triggered. I honestly don’t know what to try next, can anyone spot the issue?

Comment: What JRE are you using?

Comment: @natli Are you sure port 8080 isn't being used by something else (webserver)? I'd verify that your clients have access to the servers specified and that port 8080 is opened on both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue in one of two ways (can't be sure.)

I initially installed cassandra using a guide online which listed these repo's;

```
deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 11x main
deb-src http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 11x main
```

These are outdated, there's a `20x` version, so I updated to that.

I also replaced `jsvc` with sun's java. It's all working fine now.